# How can I receive GET/POST value beside TemplateView class

Tags: python, django

I'm leaning Python to develop a website. I use Django framework to develop. To create a VIEW using django.views.generic.base.TemplateView.
So I wanna to get value 'user_name' and 'mail' from URL, but don't know how to do that! I cannot import request within this view.

Here is Views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class MainView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'guestbook/main_page_1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #I wanna to get value 'user_name' and 'mail' from URL...
        name = request.GET.get("user_name") #temp
        email = request.GET.get("mail")     #temp

        context = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['var1'] = name
        context['var2'] = email
        return context
```

Here is Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from guestbook.views import MainView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', MainView.as_view(), name='main'),
)
```

Anybody can help me to do this!
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Request is available in `get_context_data()` as `self.request`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    name = self.request.GET.get("user_name")
    email = self.request.GET.get("mail")
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's is OK ^^